# Head nouns in ____ of ____ noun phrases

Tags: phrases, nouns

If I had a NP such as

> Thousands of lives
>
> Millions of people

which noun would be the head noun? I could make a case for each, but I assume there is a correct answer.

Comment: "Thousands" and "millions" are the heads, with the _of-_ phrases as dependents, or more specifically 'complements'.

Comment: The easy way to test this would be to remove one from your sentence: "Thousands were lost" or "Of lives were lost", which is grammatically correct?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but everyone I checked it with said the opposite. Thanks.

Comment: Really? Do you think 'Three lives' or '12 people' or 'Some examples' would be wrong, or is something special about large or unspecified numbers?

'Thousands were lost' is fine but the alternative is 'Lives were lost' not 'of lives…'. Don't you think twisting that into 'Of the lives, thousands were lost' makes the different form more important than the similar meaning? The more so considering the archaic form, 'Of lives, thousands were lost'?

Are you saying the numbers are the subjects, or what?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this example shows a limitation of the concept of head noun.

@KSHuang asks the intelligent question, which of the following is more "grammatical?"

a) "Lives were lost."
b)  "Thousands were lost."

Both the examples are perfectly grammatical.  The only difference is that as a noun phrase "thousands,"  playing a pronominal role in "Thousands were lost.", can be thought of as *lower status* grammatically than the noun "lives."

What is really going on here is that, in the absence of context, more *meaning* is carried by a) than by b). In terms of meaning, clearly a) is the better approximation to *Thousands of lives were  lost*.

So my answer is first of all to question the usefulness of the term "head noun." However, if you *are* going to use it, I suggest that you need to assess it on the basis of *lexical weight* or meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In the noun-clusters as above, " Thousands of lives" / "Millions of people" head nouns are unmistakably 'thousands' and 'millions'.

In its PDF format of shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in while dealing with English Nominal Phrase in Chapter H(pp40–102) it is said that 'of-genitive'( genitive of measure) post modifies a noun phrase. Later it is stated that numerals in English noun phrase may either be ordinal or cardinal having open-class/ close-class characteristics and function either as determinatives or heads. So numerals can also be nominals.

In English, 'preposition groups' are used as the commonest type of post modifiers having even other nouns in the larger noun cluster.

- A man of courage
- A woman without children
- Millions of men(not rats/ microbes)

We may put this to test to ascertain whether it is obligatory or dispensable by considering the post Head string, "of lives"/"of people" as preposition groups.